# How to remove left-overs from destination-out?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, html5-canvas, antialiasing

When drawing a path and then drawing exactly the same path with `globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"` like this:

```
function drawPath(ctx){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(120, 120);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(30, 40, 30, 40, 40, 120);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
  ctx.fill();
}

drawPath(ctx);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
drawPath(ctx);
```

Then there are leftovers on the anti-alised edges. This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.

Is there anything I can do to remove them(or make them not appear), and if not then is this expected to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose one anti-aliased pixel has to be drawn with alpha channel / opacity of *a*, then you remove that pixel with the same opacity, then the final opacity after drawn will be (*a* * (1 - *a*)).

So if *a* is between or 0% and 100%, then the maximum value of final opacity will be 25% at *a* = 50%.

So these artifacts are **expected**.

But if you were to remove that pixel with same opacity again for *n* times, then the final opacity would be (*a* * (1 - *a*)<sup>*n*</sup>) and its maximum value will keep decreasing. So keep drawing with `destination-out` enough times will probably remove all the artifacts. I think 8 times are enough. Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/dXVR7/

Comment: Thanks, but why can't it be `a - a`? because I am asking to remove the same alpha value which I have already drawn. or is it how destination-out works?

Comment: That's just how it works. If you add 50% to something, then you remove 50% of what's in it from it, you're left with 25% in it.